# i implemented a custom comparator to sort my ArrayList, but listview is still not sorted

Tags: java, android, listview, sorting, arraylist

OK. i made a listview that can see my custom object names I put in the arraylist.  I then wrote code to sort the Object List based on their startdate (sdate).

Cannot find solution to my problem.

However, I do not know how to test if my implementation is working since the listview where I see the objects is NOT being sorted, and retains the order in which I added them to the list.  here is the code for reference.

Comparator:

```
package app.zioueche_travelexpense;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Claim> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Claim c1, Claim c2) {
        return c1.getSDate().compareTo(c2.getSDate());
    }
}
```

where getSDate is a method in object Claim that simply returns the attribute sdate assigned to it on creation by the user.

now for the sorting problem:

here is where I sort. look for the comment

```
package app.zioueche_travelexpense;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ClaimsList implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Claim List Serialization ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 372301924739907840L;

    protected static ArrayList<Claim> claimList;
    protected ArrayList<Listener> listeners;

    public ClaimsList(){
        claimList = new ArrayList<Claim>();
        listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
    }

    public Collection<Claim> getClaim(){
        return claimList;
    }

    public void addClaim(Claim string){
        claimList.add(string);
        if (claimList.size() < 1){//SORTING HAPPENS HERE
            Collections.sort(claimList, new CustomComparator());
            notifyListeners();
        }else{
        notifyListeners();
    }}

    public void deleteClaim(Claim removeclaim){
        claimList.remove(removeclaim);
        notifyListeners();
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(){
        return claimList.size()== 0;
    }

    public void notifyListeners(){
        for (Listener listener: listeners){
            listener.update();
        }
    }
    public void addListener(Listener l){
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener l){
        listeners.remove(l);

    }


}
```

if you need any more information let me know, but I really need to solve this problem

Here is the CLaim object code:

```
package app.zioueche_travelexpense;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Claim implements Serializable{
    /**
     * Student serialized ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3325687864575767244L;
    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<Expense> expenseList;
    static Date sdate;
    private Date edate;
    private String status;

    //Claim object constructor NEED TO ADD STATUS
    public Claim(String Name, Date sdate2, Date edate2){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.expenseList = new ArrayList<Expense>();
        this.sdate = sdate2;
        this.edate = edate2;
        //this.status = status;
    }

    //get the claim name
    public String getName(){
        return this.Name;
    }

    //add an expense to the claim's expense list
    public void addExpense(Expense expense){
        expenseList.add(expense);
    }

    //change the name to a string.
    public String toString(){
        return getName();
    }

    //return the status of the string
    public String getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    //get the start date of the claim
    public Date getSDate(){
        return sdate;
    }

    //get the end date of the claim
    public Date getEDate(){
        return edate;
    }

    //change the status of the Claim.
    public void editStatus(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean equal(Object compareClaim){
        if (compareClaim != null && compareClaim.getClass()==this.getClass()){
            return this.equals((Claim) compareClaim);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return ("Claim"+getName()).hashCode();
    }

    //return the expenses list of the Claim
    public ArrayList<Expense> getExpenses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return expenseList;
    }
}
```

and then the Controller and ClaimsList:

```
package app.zioueche_travelexpense;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ClaimListController {
    private static ClaimsList claimList = null;

    static public ClaimsList getClaimList(){
        if (claimList == null){
            claimList = new ClaimsList();
        }
        return claimList;
    }

    public void addClaim(Claim claim){
        getClaimList().addClaim(claim);
    }
}

    package app.zioueche_travelexpense;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ClaimsList implements Serial

izable{

    /**
     * Claim List Serialization ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 372301924739907840L;

    protected static ArrayList<Claim> claimList;
    protected ArrayList<Listener> listeners;

    public ClaimsList(){
        claimList = new ArrayList<Claim>();
        listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
    }

    public Collection<Claim> getClaim(){
        return claimList;
    }

    public void addClaim(Claim string){
        claimList.add(string);
        if (claimList.size() > 1){
            Collections.sort(claimList, new CustomComparator());
            notifyListeners();

        }else{
        notifyListeners();
    }}

    public void deleteClaim(Claim removeclaim){
        claimList.remove(removeclaim);
        notifyListeners();
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(){
        return claimList.size()== 0;
    }

    public void notifyListeners(){
        for (Listener listener: listeners){
            listener.update();
        }
    }
    public void addListener(Listener l){
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener l){
        listeners.remove(l);

    }


    }
```

here is the claim List adapter:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.claimListView);
    Collection<Claim> claims = ClaimListController.getClaimList().getClaim();
    final ArrayList<Claim> list = new ArrayList<Claim>(claims);
    final ArrayAdapter<Claim> claimAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Claim>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(claimAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort your list only when it has 0 size

Change this condition

```
if (claimList.size() < 1)
```

to

```
if (claimList.size() > 1)
```

Additionally you have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on your adapter to refresh list.

Comment: thanks for that.  that was definitely an issue, But I still cannot see any change in  my listview.

Comment: you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() method on your adapter - list adapter

Comment: Could you add your list and adapter implementation?

Comment: yes. I will add that.  I might need help figuring out where to add the notify method. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I added the adapter code.  the adapter is made in a class called AddClaim.java

Comment: if you want to display your list on list view you have to add new element to list which you pass as parameter to your adapter. After than you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: ok. my list does show on the listview. the list view works. I just cannot get it to sort.

Comment: you have to sort   this list final ArrayList<Claim> list = new ArrayList<Claim>(claims); and after that call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Additionally Claim object can implements Comparable<Claim>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. this really got me out of a bind. if I could vote up multiple times i would.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.